# Angular expression in javascript of HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an ng-repeat but i need to use Angular expression inside javascript of my html page(of course app and controller are declared, but have not been posted here):

```html
<div ng-repeat="eleRubrique in scopeComplet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('index ' + {{$index}});
    </script>  
</div>
```

That does not work. what would be a workaround ?

Thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work for you

```
<div ng-repeat="eleRubrique in scopeComplet" ng-init="alert('index ' + $index)"></div>
```

And if you would need a more complex script I would recommend to write a function for that and call the function from `ng-init`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use double curly braces `{{}}` in JavaScript. They are meant for HTML only in Angular.

Since the JavaScript code in your HTML has nothing to do with the view, can you not achieve the same goal in the controller?

Comment: i know, it is just a way to present my problem in order to find a solution.

Comment: i want to use an angular expression in a javascript that belongs to html page